# PHPunit Framework TypeError when running my first test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have set up the PHPunit Framework for testing and upon running a simple test I am getting a TypeError below:

```
SampleTest::testTrueAssertsToTrue
TypeError: Argument 3 passed to 
SebastianBergmann\GlobalState\Snapshot::__construct() must be of the type boolean, null given, called in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 2412
```

My test case is below:

```
class SampleTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

  public function testTrueAssertsToTrue()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

The PHPunit version is ^6.2 and below is the configuration XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
      <testsuites>
        <testsuite name ="Test suite">
          <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
      </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Please help I have searched online whole day and I cant find a solution.

Comment: Please, share with us your PHPUnit version and OS... I wasn't able to reproduce your error, maybe a misconfiguration?

Comment: hi. I am using linux and I have edited my question and added the xml configuration file, the PHPUnit version is 6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using phpunit 6.2, `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` has been removed and you should be instead extending the namespaced `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase
{

  public function testTrueAssertsToTrue()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

You can verify the successful build here on travis-ci:

https://travis-ci.org/scratchers/phpunit6truetest/builds/242989226

Comment: thanx. it worked. i had actually gone back to using the prev version. After your solution the error is gone but its now saying **"No tests executed!"**...its like its not recognizing my test files. how can i fix this?

Comment: Hmm sounds like you either moved it out of the tests folder, changed your phpunit.xml, or function name doesn't start with `test`